# How to get angular ng-bootstrap breakpoints

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng-bootstrap in my project which means I can create a grid/breakpoints with:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4"></div>
</div>
```

However nice these are, bootstrap doesn't add any functionality for typescript which means that I can't use those breakpoints for animations.

What is the best way to access these breakpoints in a way that doesn't slow performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case this helps anyone, I have found that these can be imported:

```
import {MediaMatcher} from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import {ChangeDetectorRef, Component} from '@angular/core';
```

then in the component do this:

```
mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;

private _mobileQueryListener: () => void;

constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private media: MediaMatcher) {
    this.mobileQuery = media.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');
    this._mobileQueryListener = () => changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
 }

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.mobileQuery.removeListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
}
```

you can then use properties like `mobileQuery.matches` to detect the size of the screen.

*all of this was copied from an example by angular material, found [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jrgeogjgbey?file=app%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.html)

Comment: Here is a nice article about CDK with a reference to the api: https://alligator.io/angular/breakpoints-angular-cdk/